# Sharepoint 2013 provider hosted app in ADFS base sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps

We have Sharepoint 2013 single server farm and another one server with ADFS 2.0
Now configure sharepoint site with below steps:

1. Install ADFS 2.0
2. Configure ADFS with the web application as a relying party
3. Configure SharePoint Server 2013 to trust ADFS as an identity provider
4. Configure the web application to use claims-based authentication.
5. Demonstrate SAML-based claims authentication from SharePoint web application

and it will working fine with sharepoint.

Now we add one provider hosted app with this sharepoint site but we get some error.
1. When deploy from VS2012 it will give an error 
    **"Error occurred in deployment step 'Install app for SharePoint': The System Account cannot perform this action."**

1. second way we are upload app file into app catalog and try to add this app in to sharepoint site.

   - Error : “Application error when access /_layouts/15/appInv.aspx, Error=This App is not installed on this site.   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Lifecycle.SprocWrappers.GetAppInstanceById(SqlSession dbSessionWrapper, Guid siteId, Guid webId, Guid instanceId, Int32 lcid)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAppCatalog.GetAppInstance(SPWeb web, Guid appInstanceId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.AppInvPage.SetControlStateUsingAppInstanceId(String appInstanceId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.AppInvPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)”

This issue may be due to claim base authentication in  sharepoint 2013 site. because this app will working fine in windows base authenication sharepoint site.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue but I was not using ADFS. For me the solution was to use another account for installing the High Trust Provider-Hosted app. The server farm account should not be used for other services. Try using another account that has required permissions.